# Set value in Angular reactive form with controlContainer sub forms at OnInit leads to a "Cannot find form control" exception

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm doing a multilevel angular form using ReactiveForms with sub-forms adding their controls to the parent one using controlContainer directive.
The form structure is a user form component, that has a address-form child, which has itself a location-form child.
Each sub forms adds to the parent one by using the controlContainer strategy.

This part is working well. My issue appears when I want to init this form with existing values. As it has 3 levels, I can't init each level separatly, so I do a `form.setValue` from the parent `user-form.component`.
But it seems that when I set the value, the sub-component are not yet completely initialized, and haven't added their controls to the global formGroup. The `setValue` will then throw because the sub controls I want to init aren't yet existing.

What is the solution to set value to the whole form properly?

[Here's a stackblitz demo of the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7tbfox)

And here's some simplified code extracts:

The 1st level form component:

```
//user-form.component
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSubmit($event)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name" />
    </div>
    <address-form></address-form>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The 2nd level form component:

```
export class AddressForm implements OnInit {
    private readonly _fb = inject(NonNullableFormBuilder);
    private readonly _controlContainer = inject(ControlContainer);
    private readonly _cdr = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);

    form: FormGroup<AddressFormGroup>;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = this._controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
        this.form.setControl('street', this._fb.control<string>(''));
        this._cdr.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

The set value of the 1st component:

```
export class UserForm implements OnInit {    
    form = new FormGroup<UserFormGroup>({
        name: new FormControl(''),
    });

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // here it triggers the exception about controls that are not yet ready
        this.form.setValue({
            name: 'John Doh',
            street: 'Stars avenue 14',
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try moving the setValue code to ngAfterViewInit?

Answer (score 1):

As @ylerjen suggested, use the `ngAfterViewInit` hook.

But with the actual code, you will get the error, that `postalCode` has to be set too. You can overcome this, if you change `setValue` to `patchValue`. But if you want to set all control values, then of course you can use `setValue` while setting values to each control.

But then you will get the famous `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

You can solve this with a simple `setTimeout` in order to let finish Angular change detection mechanism safely:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(() =>this.form.setValue({
            name: 'John Doh',
            street: 'Stars avenue 14',
            postalCode: '111',
            city: 'nowhere'
        } as any))
    }
```

Comment: I set setTimeout and now my code is working thank you so much. I was struggling with that code because in the child component I needed to set a value programmatically.